# I have a VirtualBox Guest which switches the screen scaling back to 100% "automatically", why is that?

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, shortcut-keys

On a VirtualBox system, I setup my display with a 200% scaling (see screenshot below).

Once in while, I click to go back to my VirtualBox guest and the screen *auto-adjusts back to 100% scaling*. It feels like this could be a hotkey that Gnome thinks I hit, but looking in the hotkeys visible in the default Gnome preferences, I don't see any such thing.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

*Note: once in a while when I reboot I have a similar issue, but this is while using the VirtualBox guest, so nothing should be changing the display at that point.*

[image]

Comment: What does VPN have to do with scaling issues?

Comment: @Nmath Yes, I started writing VPN and fixed the post with VirtualBox Guest instead... Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have current VB Guest Additions installed.

Check the following settings for your VM guest...

[image]

Comment: Sorry about using the "VPN" acronym. My mistake. Note that it's not the scaling of the window as a whole, but the scaling of the Gnome Desktop inside the guest.